# using npm request to fetch a blob of files

Tags: node.js

I have some files on a CDN that I want to bring into a local project. I was trying to automate this in my `gulpfile` by using npm's `request` module.

But I'm having a difficult time getting it to work with the blob of files;

```
var core = request({ 
     url: `${cdn}/core/**/*.scss`, 
     headers: requestHeaders})
   .pipe(gulp.dest(`${local}`));
```

Is it just not possible to do this with `request`? It's not a mandatory requirement, but it sure would be convenient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Using [`gulp-remote-src`](https://github.com/ddliu/gulp-remote-src)**

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var request = require('request');
var remoteSrc = require('gulp-remote-src');

gulp.task('download', function() {
  remoteSrc(['file.scss'], {
    base: 'http://domain.com/path/'
  })
  .pipe(gulp.dest('.'));
});
```

Downloads `http://domain.com/path/file.scss` into current directory.

**Using [`fs`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html)**

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var request = require('request');
var fs = require('fs');

gulp.task('download', function() {
  request
    .get('http://domain.com/file.scss')
    .on('error', function (error) {
      console.log("Error: ", error);
    })
    .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('f.scss'));
});
```

Downloads `http://domain.com/path/file.scss` into `./f.scss`.

**Using [`vinyl-source-stream`](https://github.com/hughsk/vinyl-source-stream)**

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var request = require('request');
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');

gulp.task('download', function() {
  request
  .get('http://domain.com/path/file.scss')
  .on('error', function (error) {
    console.log("Error: ", error);
  })
  .pipe(source('.'))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('f.scss'));
});
```

Downloads `http://domain.com/path/file.scss` into `./f.scss`.

Comment: Yes, but those only work on specific files. I'm trying to do it with  blob of files.

Comment: @Ciel, do you want a "spider" scanning remote files? I don't think it is generally possible.

Comment: I've done some research since I posted this, and you're right - it's not feasible, or very wise. Should I simply close the question?